# add record via has_many with default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many

Records are added with default scope, but not with required.

```
class PostsTag
  # published is false by default
end

class Post
  has_many :posts_tags

  {published: true, private: false}.each do |key, val| 
    has_many "#{key}_tags", 
      through: "posts_tags", 
      conditions: ["posts_tags.published = ?", val],
      source: :tag
  end
end

#--------------------

Post.first.published_tags << Tag.first
Post.first.published_tags.count # = 0
Post.first.private_tags.count # = 1
```

What do I wrongly? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a new Tag into published_tags does not set its published attribute to true by default.

What you need to do is to extend the published_tags association and override the << method of it to set the published attribute to true upon insertion. The code will look something like that:

```
has_many :published_tags do
  def <<(tag)
    tag.published = true
    proxy_association.owner.posts_tags+= [tag]
  end
end
```

I've written a full working example of exactly this case [here](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/activerecord-association-extensions/), you should definitely have a look at it to get some more insights.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected a bit question, published flag is placed in PostsTag model. Your answer works fine for simple has_many association, but in looks like it needs be corrected for "has_many through" associations...

Comment: It is possible to add two models PublishedPostsTag and PrivatePostsTag with default_scope, but it looks a bit ugly.